# Cannot insert duplicate key row in object with unique index The duplicate key value SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm getting this error:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.CLIENT' with unique
>   index 'CLIENT_idx_A'. The duplicate key value is (14441828, 1).

When I checked, the indexes, it's created like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [CLIENT_idx_A] ON [dbo].[CLIENT] 
(
     [SOURCE_SYSTEM_CLIENT_ID] ASC,
     [SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID] ASC
)
     WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF,
           SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
           DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF,
           ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON [PRIMARY]
```

Actually, I want to update one value in `SOURCE_SYSTEM_CLIENT_ID` and my `SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID` is 1 for all the `SOURCE_SYSTEM_CLIENT_ID` that I want to update. So I think, its encountering duplicate. How can I solve this?

Comment: You are encountering that error because you will result in 2 records with (338393005,1). If that is allowed, you need to remove that index. That's the solution.

Comment: Do I need to delete the index , run the update query and then CREATE the index again? OR is there any way to remove index?

Comment: Your database is constrained to not allow more than one client record per system. If this rule is not longer valid and duplicates are allowed, then you can drop the index, re-add the index as non-unique, and run your update.

Comment: Or if the index is there for a reason, instead of updating records delete the records you are trying to update which would lead to duplicates. And, of course, add the records which would not.

Comment: what's the statement that throws the above error?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously(?) the following query will return the row that your update statement is duplicating with;

```
select *
from [dbo].[CLIENT]
where [SOURCE_SYSTEM_CLIENT_ID] = 338393005
and [SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID] = 1
```

What you do to resolve this is up to you, either the record that exists is valid and you want to update some of it's columns, or you may wish to delete the conflicting row before performing the action that generated the error originally.

Deleting the constraint is a bit extreme if you're not deliberately redeveloping the schema and that will leave you vulnerable to errors in your SQL and the application which could corrupt your data. Tread here only if you really know what you're doing and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Records that are exists are valid and I do not want to delete it. I just want to update few records and some of the columns.

Comment: Is it an SQL statement that you execute which gives the error or are you trying the update in an application that passes this error to you? Why are you trying to change [SOURCE_SYSTEM_CLIENT_ID] for an existing record, this is concerning. You need to add more information to your question, ideally the update statement if available.